# Why select_tag displays only one column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following **select_tag** in my view:

```
   <%= select_tag :users, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id','firstname' , 'lastname') %></p></br>
```

I want to display the firstname and lastname in the select_tag, but it always displays the first parameter after the **'id'** in this case the firstname.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
<%= select(:users, :id, @users.map {|u| [u.firstname + " " + u.lastname,u.id]}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im confident that options_for_select only allows you to put 1) The value that you want each option to have, 2) The id or label you want that option to have.

What you'd do is, in your User model, set a method to concatenate both the user first and last name into one and then use that as your option_for_select id.

User Model

```
def userFullName
   self.firstname+' '+self.lastname
end
```

Then use it in your select_tag as this:

```
<%= select_tag :users, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id','userFullName') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Api Doc for `options_from_collection_for_select` you can get this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

If you only want to display the options, that's is the right way to do it.

You only specify a 4th parameter if you want to preselect one option.

If you want to concatenate the name, you could do it as Oscar Valdez is telling you to.

Check more info for `options_from_collection_for_select` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select